# Taking a SUM of a text field representing a column name in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's a sample of my table

```
[myTable]
id | random1 | random2 | random3 | random4
1  | 123     | 5357    | 10      | 642 
2  | 423     | 34      | 20      | 531
3  | 9487    | 234     | 30      | 975
4  | 34      | 123     | 40      | 864
```

Here's my current query, but it isn't working like I'd expect it to:

```
SELECT 
    cols.*,
    (SELECT SUM(cols.column_name) FROM myTable t)
FROM 
    (SELECT
        table_name::text, column_name::text
    FROM 
        information_schema.columns 
    where 
        table_name = 'myTable') as cols
```

I'm getting the error: function sum(text) does not exist - which makes sense. I'm pretty sure that mysql is can be messy enough to allow a reference like that, but I don't know how to do this in postgres.

What I'd really like to have is an end result somewhere along the lines of...

```
table_name | column_name | sum
myTable    | id          | 10
myTable    | random1     | 10067
myTable    | random2     | 5748
myTable    | random3     | 100
myTable    | random4     | 3012
```

I want to take this query a lot further, but I'm getting really hung up on being able to reference the column name.

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries are static. They select before-known columns from before-known tables. You cannot make them look up table names and columns from the database dictionary and then magically glue these names into themselves.

What you can do: Write a program (Java, C#, PHP, whatever you like) doing the following:

1. Send a query to the DBMS to find the column names for the table you are interested in.
2. Build a SQL query string with the column names got.
3. Send this query to the DBMS.

Comment: That was my worry.. I'm still hoping there is a pure sql solution for this, but I'm starting to think it might not exist right now.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @tableName varchar(255) = 'myTable'  --Change this to the table name you want

/*create table and column name dataSet and insert values*/
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#objectSet') is not null
    drop table #objectSet
create table #objectSet
    (table_name varchar(256),
    columnID int,
    column_name varchar(256),
    [sum] int)

insert into #objectSet
    (table_name,
    columnID,
    column_name)
select O.name table_name,
    C.column_id columnID,
    C.name column_name
from sys.all_objects O
join sys.all_columns C
    on O.object_id = C.object_id
join sys.types T
    on C.user_type_id = T.user_type_id
where O.object_id = object_id(@tableName)
    and T.name in ('int', 'tinyint', 'smallint', 'bigint')   --Columns with Aggregatable datatypes only, all other columns will be excluded from the set.


/*Create loop variables for each column*/
declare @SQL as varchar(4000),
    @counter int = 1,
    @maxCount int

select @maxCount = SQ.maxCount
from (  select count(*) maxCount
        from #objectSet OS) SQ

/*Run loop, updating each column as it goes*/
while @counter <= @maxCount
    begin
        select @SQL = 'update OS set OS.[sum] = SQ.[sum] from #objectSet OS join (select sum(DS.' + OS.column_name + ') [sum] from ' + @tableName + ' DS) SQ on OS.column_name = ''' + OS.column_name + ''''
        from #objectSet OS
        where OS.columnID = @counter

        exec (@SQL)

        select @counter += 1
    end


/*Display Results*/
select OS.table_name,
    OS.column_name,
    OS.[sum]
from #objectSet OS
```

Using system object tables, some dynamic T-SQL, and a loop should do it.